# Sylius: Not able to embed a list of products into a view / customize a repository

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I want to embed a list of products into a view as described in the docs:
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/embedding-products.html (See also: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/repository.html)

I copy & pasted mostly the code snippets from the page above. I generated the file `src/AppBundle/Repository/ProductRepository.php` with the code from the docs:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository as BaseProductRepository;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelInterface;

class ProductRepository extends BaseProductRepository
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function findLatestByChannelAndTaxonCode(ChannelInterface $channel, $code, $count)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->innerJoin('o.channels', 'channel')
            ->addOrderBy('o.createdAt', 'desc')
            ->andWhere('o.enabled = true')
            ->andWhere('channel = :channel')
            ->innerJoin('o.taxons', 'taxon')
            ->andWhere('taxon.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('channel', $channel)
            ->setParameter('code', $code)
            ->setMaxResults($count)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

Then I registered it in `app/config/config.yml` (again 1:1 copy&paste):

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                repository: AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
```

And I configured the routing in `app/config/routing.yml` (1:1 copy&paste).

```
app_shop_partial_product_index_latest_by_taxon_code:
    path: /latest/{code}/{count} # configure a new path that has all the needed variables
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.product:indexAction # you make a call on the Product Controller's index action
        _sylius:
            template: $template
            repository:
                method: findLatestByChannelAndTaxonCode # here use the new repository method
                arguments:
                    - "expr:service('sylius.context.channel').getChannel()"
                    - $code
                    - $count
```

Then I want it to render in my index.html.twig:

```
<h2 class="ui horizontal section divider header">My custom title</h2>

{{ render(url('app_shop_partial_product_index_latest_by_taxon_code', {'code': 'mugs', 'count': 4, 'template': '@SyliusShop/Product/_horizontalList.html.twig'})) }}
```

The title is visible and I'm using the sample data, so there's an existing taxon with the code 'mugs'. But there is no product list visible.

Did I skip something in the docs? I'm new to Symfony, so maybe I forgot something obvious? And how can I debug this myself?

**Edit:** The current version of the docs is outdated, see https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a new concept for productTaxon, therefore the correct function is:

```
public function findLatestByChannelAndTaxonCode(ChannelInterface $channel, $code, $count)
        {
            return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
                ->innerJoin('o.channels', 'channel')
                ->andWhere('o.enabled = true')
                ->andWhere('channel = :channel')
                ->innerJoin('o.productTaxons', 'productTaxons')
                ->addOrderBy('productTaxons.position', 'asc')
                ->innerJoin('productTaxons.taxon', 'taxon')
                ->andWhere('taxon.code = :code')
                ->setParameter('code', $code)
                ->setParameter('channel', $channel)
                ->setMaxResults($count)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        }
```

The [documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/embedding-products.html) was updated as well.